# Need to stop a numericupdown from changing numbers

Tags: c#, numericupdown

I have several numericupdowns which all contribute to an overall score. Every time one of them ticks up the score goes down. I need some way to stop the numericupdowns from going any higher when the score is already at 0.

Comment: Please provide us with some code to better understand the issue.

Comment: Are these controls change by a user? Are they just being changed in code?

Answer (score 0):

show us your code -
You could do a check and if the value is less than 0, make it 0.

```
if(numericUpDown1.Value < 0)
{
  numericUpDown1.Value = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am ommiting how you modify your score `NumericUpDown` and here is how you prevent your other `NumericUpDown` controls to be modified after score reaches 0:

**VB.NET**

```
Dim Num1 As NumericUpDown
Dim Num2 As NumericUpDown
Dim NumScore As NumericUpDown

Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged
    If NumScore.Value = 0 Then
        Num1.ReadOnly = True
        Num1.Increment = 0
        Num2.ReadOnly = True
        Num2.Increment = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

**C#**

```
private NumericUpDown Num1;
private NumericUpDown Num2;
private NumericUpDown NumScore;

private void NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (NumScore.Value == 0)
    {
        Num1.ReadOnly = true;
        Num1.Increment = 0;
        Num2.ReadOnly = true;
        Num2.Increment = 0;
    }
}
```